# Cakephp 2 how to paginate a model but restrict the results to only those with a conditional associated model

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, associations, cakephp-2.3

I’m working on a legacy Cakephp 2 system and having some issues figuring out how the pagination is supposed to work.

I have a `Users` model, a `SystemSessions` model and a `Locations` model. `Users hasmany SystemSessions` and each `SystemSession` has a `location_id`. I’m trying to find out how I can paginate `Users` to only show `Users` who have `SystemSessions` with a particular `location_id`.

If I try:

```
$conditions['conditions']['User.role'] = 'User';
$conditions['contain'] = array(
    'SystemSession' => array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'SystemSession.location_id' => '34'
        )
    )
);
```

That will pull back every `User` and under those users, there will be `SystemSessions` with the `location_id` of 34, however, the `Users` who don't have `SystemSessions` from that location appear in the results too (just with empty `SystemSessions` array).

What I want is to only pull back `Users` who have `SystemSessions` from that location, `Users` who haven't got a `SystemSessions` from that particular location, shouldn't appear in the results.

Normally I could just loop through and remove the ones I don't want, but because I'm trying to paginate the results, that would throw off all the paging and so on.

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replicate what you'd do on SQL level to solve this, that is for example using a join to pull in and filter by the associated data. You can't solve this with `contain` alone, as `hasMany` associations are being retrieved in a separate query, hence why your condition only affects the associated data.

Assuming `$conditions` are your finder options:

```php
// ...
$conditions['joins'] = array(
    array(
        'table' => 'system_sessions',
        'alias' => 'SystemSession',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => array(
            'SystemSession.user_id = User.id',
            'SystemSession.location_id' => 34,
        )
    )
);
$conditions['group'] = 'User.id';
```

This would apply an `INNER` join on the `system_sessions` table with your desired conditions, eg something like:

```sql
// ...
INNER JOIN
    system_sessions SystemSession ON 
        SystemSession.user_id = User.id AND
        SystemSession.location_id = 34
GROUP BY
    User.id
```

and thus filter out all users for which no match exists. To retrieve the associated data you'd still need to use `contain`!

See also

- **[Cookbook > Models > Associations: Linking Models Together > Joining tables](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables)**

Comment: Thank you for this. It's worked as expected :-)